# How to use a for loop to loop through all the numbers between two integers in java

Tags: java

So i am completely stumped on how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated, what i want to do is basically get all the numbers between two integers.

So say i had the numbers:
254 and 259 
I would want to output the following numbers:
255, 256, 257, 258

Also i will want to add these numbers to a list and be able to output how many numbers are in that list, so in this case there would be 4 numbers in the list.

I am using this to cycle through an area of land.

Comment: I find it somewhat puzzling that a person who has asked normal quality questions in the past (ie. with code samples and showing a modicum of familiarity with Java) would ask such a low quality beginner's question.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Maybe they've been "disregard this, I **** ****"'d. :-P

Answer (score 2):

```
public static List<Integer> getOpenRange(int start, int end) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; ++i)
        result.add(i);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Trouble is, that won't give you are asking...

Comment: @PeteBelford , elaborate please

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] array = new int[max-min]; 

for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++)
{
    array[i - min - 1] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int start = 254;
    int end = 259;
    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = start+1; i < end; i++) {
        //Prints the numbers exclusive...
        System.out.println(i);
        //Adds the numbers to the list
        numberList.add(i);          
    }

    //Prints the length of the list.
    System.out.println("Size " + numberList.size());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
int min, max;
```

To output in a loop:

```
for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

To determine size, you don't need a list:

```
int size = max - min - 1;
```